# Is there a faster way to copy and paste formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I currently use this code that filters a column and pastes in the formatting from another table.

```
examtable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="H"
MainTemp.ListRows(1).Range.Copy
examtable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

examtable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
MainTemp.ListRows(2).Range.Copy
examtable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

examtable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="T"
MainTemp.ListRows(3).Range.Copy
examtable.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

examtable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

As the table that it is being pasted to varies in length, sometimes it can take a while for this part of code to complete. Is there a faster way to achieve this?

Comment: If you know which formats you want to apply, then apply them directly instead of copying them, this might be faster then. For example if it is about borders then just create the borders with VBA instead of copying all formats. • Other option might be conditional formatting (depends on what you are exactly trying to achieve). • Can you describe what your actual goal is? Because this looks like a [x/y-problem question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Have a template and drop the new data into it...

Comment: @SolarMike Depends on the data. If the data has extensive formulas that might not be faster than applying some formattings, as it would trigger a complete recalculation of all formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

before you enter that phase of your code

and

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

when you leave it

Neither "fix" your problem directly, but both are generic speedups for operating on workbooks with formulae in them.